# How could I check to see if a point is inside a cone projected by another point?

Tags: 3d, convex-cone

I use CesiumJS, a javascript library, to render entities in a 3-dimensional space. I need to detect if one entity is "viewing" another entity. My initial thought is to use a cone to represent the field of view of the entity. I need to be able to make the cone variable angle and height. What is the most efficient way to check if Entity 2 is inside the cone emitted by Entity 1? I am doing this calculation a bunch of times so I am trying to find a way to do it efficiently.

In Cesium, my entities are plotted using Lat/long/alt, which I figured I could think of as X,Y,Z. I also know the orientation of each point, so I know which way to make the cone emit. Cesium has some built-in functions for checking intersections but all seem to use rays or lines emitting from entity 1, which don't give me my desired output. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that your point where you check the viewing is $\vec P_0(x_0,y_0,z_0)$, you are looking in a direction $\vec d(d_x,d_y,d_z)$ in a cone with opening (angle between side and axis) $\alpha$, and you want to check if $\vec P_1(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ is inside the cone. Then you want the angle between the vector $\vec P_1-\vec P_0$ and $\vec d$ to be less than $\alpha$. You can write this using scalar product:
$$\cos\left(\angle(\vec P_1-\vec P_0, \vec d)\right)=\frac{(\vec P_1-\vec P_0)\cdot \vec d}{|\vec P_1-\vec P_0||\vec d|}\\=\frac{(x_1-x_0)d_x+(y_1-y_0)d_y+(z_1-z_0)dz}{\sqrt{(x_1-x_0)^2+(y_1-y_0)^2+(z_1-z_0)^2}\sqrt{dx^2+dy^2+d_z^2}}$$
If the viewing angle is smaller than $\alpha$, then the last expression must be greater than $\cos\alpha$.

Comment: I am not sure if I am 100% correct in using your formula, but basically I converted my Latitude/Longitude/Altitude to cartesian3 points because I was using a helper function in my code to generate the directional vector which use cartesian 3 points. Long story short. plugging directly into that bottom formula my resulting number is -730.6584673334336. The numbers I have and am using are large and fairly precise. Do I need to take the cos of that and convert to degrees?  The only reason I ask is because that gives me something like:  -13.52 deg. Otherwise I feel like I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Here is a stackblitz that is just a javascript application running that formula with the variables I have:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-vkpnir?file=index.js

Comment: The `^` operator is not square in javascript. It is exclusive or.

Comment: Ok, after fixing all the code to use `Math.Pow()` my result is ~-0.00769.... and if I understand correctly I would want to check to make sure that the result I got is less than the angle of my cone correct?  If I assume my cone's angle is 5deg then I would want the number I get to be less than or equal to -2.5 to 2.5 deg's is that correct?

Comment: The number is right, but it's the cosine of the angle. So it means that it's close to $90^\circ$. $\cos 2.5^\circ=0.99904822158$. And you want your number to be greater than that. When you are looking straight at the other object, the cosine is $1$.

Comment: Ok, so in this case getting the -0.007.... would mean I am outside the 2.5deg's (.9990....) since I am less than the cos of the angle. I think the reason I am confused is because the issue must be somewhere on my end with my directional vector. Looking at the 3D models It seems the angle should be much closer. 

 If I understand it all then my -0.00769 would be a fairs way outside of the viewing angle if we assume it is something like 5deg-10deg.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the real direction between points was close (parallel)  to $(1,0,0)$, while the direction you were looking at was close to $(0,1,-1)$, so almost $90^\circ$ apart. Then the cosine of the angle between the two is close to $0$. A quick trick would be to divide each element of the direction vector by the largest absolute value. Then do the same with the difference in positions. This would allow you to have a better intuition what is the angle between the two. If I have to guess, the function that gives you the direction is wrong.

Comment: That is my guess, it a function that we wrote a little while back for generating a point in front of the entity. That is what I was using as it take into consideration the conversion of Lat/Long/Alt to cartesian 3 points that CesiumJS uses. The visual I render appears to be in the correct direction but like you I suspect something is wrong. The Cyan line here is what I was using as my direction, or rather the end point of that line: https://imgur.com/a/5ngmnBZ

Comment: Sorry, just thinking out loud here. But I mentioned the function I used to generate my Direction vector really just generated an endpoint for a line. If I subtract the endpoint from the start point and use that would that I should get better results, correct?

Comment: It should. It's hard to check, since I don't have the full picture of what you are doing.

Comment: Yeah, it's hard to share sufficient material on StackExchange. Unfortunately, I am not sure it's still what I am looking for. The numbers I've been using are hand-picked from tens of thousands of sets of numbers because these should be pretty close and should result in an intercept. Here is a freeze frame of the rendering in Cesium: https://imgur.com/a/QsDRBnv The intercept happens when a cone around that cyan line out of the red entity. Intersects the blue entity (the center point) If I use an angle of 35deg and compare it against the Cos of the result of the expression, it does appear right.

Comment: If the cyan line is defined by two points (origin and the far away point), then the direction is given by the difference in coordinates

Comment: Yes, the start point I use for the cyan line is the center point of the red entity (not fully pictured) and the end point is calculated using a function based off this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58021985/create-a-point-in-a-direction-in-cesiumjs I have a x offset of 10,000 with no y or z offsets just  like their rotationScaled variable in the accepted answer.

Comment: When I compare the results, do I need to compare the cos of the result against the Cos of our angle? 

Currently, I am doing
 `Math.cos(fullExpression)` compared to `Math.cos(35(Math.PI/180))`

Comment: No. Your fullExpression is the cosine of the angle. So you want `fullExpression>Math.cos(35(Math.PI/180))`

Comment: That's what I thought but was hoping wasn't the case, if I do that it never seems very close. For instance, the numbers from that rendering above give me -0.581926...... which doesn't give me much confidence because if that rendering above is that far off then I am doing something wrong I believe. More digging.